# Fetch data quicker from an API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a weather app project. I have three cities right now with a select tag. My purpose is that when a user selects another city, I try to pass it into my API call. But, even though there is no error, the API call works later. I mean when the user selects Y city, the API call shows the previous, for instance, X. When the user switches it into Z city, the API call shows Y city not Z city. And I do not think that aysnc function causes this because without async, it still works in the same way. How can I make them sync?

This is the line my API call exists:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchApi() {
      const res = await axios(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${getSelection}&appid=c681e6e33ec339728fdf88e0b24a2a01`)
      setTakeData(res.data)
    }
    fetchApi()
  }, [])
```

This is the component where "getSelection" comes from:

```
function Header() {
    const [selection, setSelection] = useState({value: "Ankara"})
    const cities = ["İstanbul", "Ankara", "İzmir"]

    const handleSelection = (e) => {
        setSelection({value: e.target.value})
return (
        <div>
            <div className="header">
                <select name="selection" value={selection.value} onChange={handleSelection}>
                    <option value="İstanbul">{cities[0]}</option>
                    <option value="Ankara">{cities[1]}</option>
                    <option value="İzmir">{cities[2]}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <ApiCall getSelection={selection.value} />
        </div>   
    )
```

This is the console:

```
This is from header.jsx:  İzmir
This is from ApiCall.jsx:  İzmir
UPDATED CITY:  Istanbul
This is from ApiCall.jsx:  İzmir
UPDATED CITY:  Istanbul
This is from ApiCall.jsx:  İzmir
UPDATED CITY:  Istanbul
This is from ApiCall.jsx:  İzmir
UPDATED CITY:  Istanbul
This is from ApiCall.jsx:  İzmir
UPDATED CITY:  İzmir
```

As you see, it is updated at the last.

Comment: have you tried adding `getSelection` in your `useEffect()` array of dependencies `[]` ?

Comment: thanks for the `appid` - I would recommend *burning* that one and generating a new one, because even if you edit the question, those with high enough access can still see the original code

Comment: @OmarDieh There is a little delay but it works!!!. Many thanks!

Comment: @JaromandaX Since this is not a real project, I thought this is not a big problem to harcode it. But, thanks for the suggestions. I will keep in the mind

Comment: @Hyperienn - if that isn't a real appid, then all good - also, I would never use it anyway (I don't have much call for weather info on my sites) - so many people post their real openweathermap appid's

Answer (score 0):

You can let the `Header` component take care of the data fetching and only provide the response data down to your rendering component.

You speed up the data fetching by triggering the fetching directly on the button click.

You can archive that by moving the fetching logic into the Header component and only passing the data down to the render component. It is best practice to also move the `useEffect` in the `Header` component so that all the state logic is in one place. To refactor this code a bit you can specify one single method that fetches based on parameters data and use that function in the places where you want to fetch the information.

```
const INITIAL_CITY = 'Ankara'

const fetchApi = async (cityName) => {
      const res = await axios(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${cityName}&appid=c681e6e33ec339728fdf88e0b24a2a01`)
      return res.data
    }

// Defines an unassigned immutable array/object that is not reinitialized on any rerendering
const CITIES = Object.freeze(["İstanbul", "Ankara", "İzmir"])

function Header() {
    const [selection, setSelection] = useState({value: INITIAL_CITY})
    const [takeData, setTakeData] = useState(null)
    

    useEffect(() => {
      // Initial loading of first city
      fetchApi(INITIAL_CITY).then(setTakeData)
    }, [])

    const handleSelection = (e) => {
        const newCityName = e.target.value
        setSelection({value: newCityName})
        fetchApi(newCityName).then(setTakeData)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="header">
                <select name="selection" value={selection.value} onChange={handleSelection}>
                    <option value="İstanbul">{CITIES[0]}</option>
                    <option value="Ankara">{CITIES[1]}</option>
                    <option value="İzmir">{CITIES[2]}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            {* I suppose that the ApiCall component also renders the data *}
            <ApiCall takeData={takeData} />
        </div>   
    )
```

Final note: I moved all functions that do not contain any state logic or return JSX outside of the Component. That makes the component leaner and easier for changes in the feature.